# not declared in this scope error msg

Tags: c++

I gettin not declared in this scope error msg also declared .h file &  EngineFactory  class in .h

```
EngineFactory *engineFactory = NULL;

engineFactory = new EngineFactory();

EngineFactory->Create();

EngineFactory->destroy();
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you use a namespace?

Comment: We're gonna need some more code of yours. Where does the error come from?

Answer (score 2):

There is two problems in the code:

1. Your code is not inside a function. Place it in main() function, and it'll work better.
2. EngineFactory->Create(); has uppercase EngineFactory, while your variable is lowercase.

Comment: True! OP is not using the created object!